# Data Table: How to show the show Entries dropdown beside the Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries in the table structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, datatables, jquery-pagination

Is it Possible to show the show Entries dropdown beside the Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries in the table structure.I want to display the show entries dropdown at the bottom along with pagination and  Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries.

Thanks in Advance!!!

The image is looking like

Now I want to show the show dropdown entries as per second scenario.

[image: the image is with show dropdown at top]

[image: Now i want to show the show dropdown entries as per the image two.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through dataTables "[**`dom`**](http://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)"-attribute. `i` is info, `l` is lengthmenu, insert `l` just before `i` :

```js
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
   //default is lfrtip 
   dom: 'frtlip'    
});

//lengthmenu -> add a margin to the right and reset clear 
$(".dataTables_length").css('clear', 'none');
$(".dataTables_length").css('margin-right', '20px');

//info -> reset clear and padding
$(".dataTables_info").css('clear', 'none');
$(".dataTables_info").css('padding', '0');
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/psvf3z75/**

[image]

Comment: thanks for solution but the functionality is not working like when i select value from dropdown after selecting it is fading away like it disappears after selecting the value.

Comment: @Bhairav, have completely rewritten the answer. I think it is more correct to use some of the dataTables builtin features rather than doing it by a "hack" that can cause all sorts of problems. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: thanks for the quick response still it is not working for me .here in jsfiddle it is working...the first code was looking good but missed functionality there after i am trying with the updated solutions it is not working for me.

Comment: @Bhairav, what does not work exactly? What version of dataTables are you using?

Comment: @Bhairav - I guessed it was that, use sDom instead of dom - here is an 1.9.4 example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pq7ms2fe/** (updated with a little margin-top)

Comment: And David we are not using the datatable css we are using our customized css.

Comment: @Bhairav, yes - but the elements are the same. At least now the lengthmenu and info is aside and you can style them as you wish.